# Flower with one petal long

Tags: flowers

I saw a violet flower with six petals. One petal is significantly longer. What will be the explanation for that?
[image]

Location: Ontario, CA

Comment: Sure. I overlooked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a *Crocus*. In nature there is variation on different levels, and for flower characteristics, you can have these three different levels:

1. Variation among localities
2. Variation among individuals
3. Variation within individuals

The variation within individuals can be caused by micro environmental factors (for example light availability), difference in tissue age, spatial variation in nutrient availability, and/or mutations (see scientific ref [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3375002/)).

Comment: Or simpler put: Just as humans may have asymmetrical features like a difference in foot length or ear size, this crocus has a larger petal.

Comment: @naveen: as you see the leaves are cutted, so this plant growth in a disturbed place, and such condition helps such "defects"

Comment: @Giacomo: Squirrel :)